# Read variable column names from excel in pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I am new to Pentaho.
I have excel input file with fixed number of columns but the column name changes. I want to capture the column names. I tried using "Metadata Structure of Stream" as well as UDJC

```
inputRowMeta = getInputRowMeta();
fieldNames = inputRowMeta.getFieldNames();
```

In both the cases I am getting the field names from what was defined from the first excel. So whatever is defined in the "Fields" tab in the "Microsoft Excel Input" comes out as the output for "Metadata Structure of Stream". What I am looking for is if the input excel file column name changes then the metadata output should also change. Is there a way I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know fieldnames at design-time, you must treat column headers as data.  Metadata injection can be used to convert data to metadata, then.  You will find a demo of this feature in your Kettle samples folder.